# Can OpenCloud or other cloud software support nodes across multiple domains?

Tags: cloud, cloud-hosting

As the title suggests I would like to know if, specifically opencloud, can support connecting of nodes across different domains.  I've read and read and in all cases I've been able to find the assumption is made that all nodes will be be on the same network.

So for example:
Lets say 6 people buy computers and they want to build a private cloud using separate computers from each of their individual houses.

Can any one tell me if this is possible, and if so, point me towards some documentation that might get me going.  Thank you very much!

Just as a note; I've considered the option of VPN, but do not want to go that route.